# Solving Fizzbuzz Using Rubys Enumerable Module?

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

Hey I was given the fizzbuzz task recently and I had answered with the usual,

```
if ((i%3==0) || (i.to_s.include?('3'))) && ((i%7==0) || (i.to_s.include?('7')))
p 'Fizzbuzz'
elsif (i%3==0) || (i.to_s.include?('3'))
p 'Fizz'
elsif (i%7==0) || (i.to_s.include?('7'))
p 'Buzz'
else
p i
end
```

and when asked to shorten it I tried using ternary operators:

```
p (i%3<1 || i.to_s.include?('3')) ? ((i%7<1 || i.to_s.include?('7')) ? "Fizzbuzz" : "Fizz") : ((i%7<1 || i.to_s.include?('7')) ? "Buzz" : i)
```

but when asked to solve it using the Enumerable methods(select,reject,collect etc) I was well stumped...Any body tried this before??

The select/collect methods were specificaly mentioned so I'm guessing that he had something like this in mind(excuse the crappy code) 
(1..100).select { |i| i % 3 == 0 }.collect { "fizz" } 
but i'm stuck when trying to do this for the 3 conditions and print out the result(ie iterate through the output array) :\

Comment: It is generally considered a bad practice to nest ternary operator expressions.

Comment: What are you doing with expressions like `i.to_s.include?('3')`? Do you want numbers like `31` to be classified together with multiples of 3?

Comment: The usual? Just creating a string for every number to compare it with another number converted to a string? Well, in my time ...

Comment: Yes, the solution needs to return Fizz if the number contains or is a multiple of 3 etc..

Comment: Are you sure he didn't mean that he wanted you to include the code for enumerating over the numbers rather than use Enumerable for deciding what to print?

Comment: Off topic, but still fun to [look](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88/obfuscated-fizzbuzz-golf) at.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not much help now, but I've produced a gem (fizzbuzzard) that monkey patches `Fixnum` such that all multiples of three print as `Fizz`, all multiples of five etc etc. Interviewers will respect you for using your knowledge of existing libraries rather than pointlessly re-solving solved problems.

Get it from rubgems [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/fizzbuzzard) and find the source [here](http://github.com/rsslldnphy/fizzbuzzard).

The part I'm proudest of? The test suite. Output reproduced here:

```
(0h8m|master) [fizzbuzzard] $ rspec
.

Finished in 0 seconds
1 example, FIZZBUZZ failures
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fizzbuzz(i)
  [nil,nil,"Fizz",nil, nil,nil,"Buzz"].each_with_index do |fizz_or_buzz, idx|
    print fizz_or_buzz if (i.to_i % (1+idx)).zero?
  end
end
```

If the interviewer doesn't laugh, then it's probably not going to be a good fit (for me anyways).

Note that `print` doesn't add a newline (vs `p`)

See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Ruby for more common solutions.

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'i' for main:Object`

Comment: I asssumed `i` was set beforehand (as in the original question) @DanielXMoore

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little dense but fun. It abuses arrays and some functional methods slightly to avoid using any `if` statements.

```
rules = {
  3 => ["fizz"],
  7 => ["buzz"]
}

(1..100).map do |n|
  [rules.map do |key, value|
    value[n % key]
  end.compact.join, n.to_s].find do |word|
    !word.empty?
  end
end.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clean to repeat the same conditionals.

```
p case [
  i.%(3).zero? || i.to_s.include?("3"),
  i.%(7).zero? || i.to_s.include?("7")
]
when [true, true] then "Fizzbuzz"
when [true, false] then "Fizz"
when [false, true] then "Buzz"
when [false, false] then i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This hands you back the results in an array of strings, you can do whatever you want with them at that point.

```
results = (1..100).to_a.collect do |i|
  f = ((i%3).zero? || i.to_s.include?('3'))
  b = ((i%7).zero? || i.to_s.include?('7'))
  "#{:fizz if f}#{:buzz if b}#{i unless f || b}"
end
p results
```